# Knockout IE 8 option length error

Tags: knockout.js

When using knockout 2.2.0 with a dropdown box in IE8 we are getting an error. In IE 8 the length of the array is shown as 2 instead of 1. It works fine in IE9 and above and other browsers.

I've put the code in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dWsnE/1/).

The UI code looks like:

```
<script>
   function EmailDomain(text, value) {
       this.DisplayText = text;
       this.Value = value;
   }
   function VM(){
       self.EmailDomains = ko.observableArray([
            new EmailDomain("aaa.com", "aaa.com"),
        ]);

       self.SelectedEmailDomain = ko.observable(self.EmailDomains()[0]);
   }
</script>

<select data-bind="options: EmailDomains, optionsText: 'DisplayText', value: SelectedEmailDomain"></select>
```

[image: the screen where i an getting the error]

Comment: I downloaded the knockout2.2.0 version, I am having the same problem. I have created jsFiddle url http://jsfiddle.net/dWsnE/1/. Run this in IE 8 or in IE 8 mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't had a chance to test this yet as I don't have IE8 on this machine, but it might be because you have an accidental comma at the end of your array that isn't necessary?

```
self.EmailDomains = ko.observableArray([
    new EmailDomain("aaa.com", "aaa.com") // Removed: ,
]);
```

IE does some crazy things when there are commas out of place so its worth a try!

Comment: I've tested and can confirmed the trailing comma is the culprit!